# jquery - checking for change in "get" populated div

Tags: jquery, get

I have a page "productCalculator.php" that asks the user to select a category (from a select).  Once they do, I populate a div (based on their decision) by using $.get("getProducts.php").

The new div contains another select, with the id of productID.  I tried to put the following code into "productCalculator.php":

```
$(function() {
    $("#productID").change(function() {
        $("pageTitle").html("Step 1: Select A Category");
        var prodID = $("#productID").val();

        alert(prodID);
    });
});
```

When I change the product on the select, it doesn't execute.  However, If I put the aforementioned script into the "getProducts.php" code, it works just fine.

How can I get the change listener to work with content generated by "get" calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach the event for the elements created in the future. Your element with id `productID` does not exist in DOM while you make the event binding so it is not attached to the element which gets added to the DOM dynamically during the ajax call. Event delegation helps you in this case to attach the event to the document head or any other container that exists in DOM at any time and have the event delegated to the input `#productID` that is added later.

```
$(document).on('change', "#productID", function() { // Use another container instead of document head.
        $("pageTitle").html("Step 1: Select A Category");
        var prodID = $("#productID").val();

        alert(prodID);
    });
```